# How to convert an object to a string in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Im trying to follow the spark example - https://www.javaworld.com/article/2972863/big-data/open-source-java-projects-apache-spark.html

but get compilation error on this line -->input.flatMap( s -> Arrays.asList( s.split( " " ) ) );

```
Type mismatch cannot convert from JavaRDD<object> to JavaRDD<String>
```

Code:-

```
public class WordCountTask
{



    public static void wordCountJava8( String filename )
    {
        // Define a configuration to use to interact with Spark
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Work Count App");

        // Create a Java version of the Spark Context from the configuration
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        // Load the input data, which is a text file read from the command line
        JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile( filename );

        // Java 8 with lambdas: split the input string into words
        JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap( s -> Arrays.asList( s.split( " " ) ) );

        // Java 8 with lambdas: transform the collection of words into pairs (word and 1) and then count them
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = words.mapToPair( t -> new Tuple2( t, 1 ) ).reduceByKey( (x, y) -> (int)x + (int)y );

        // Save the word count back out to a text file, causing evaluation.
        counts.saveAsTextFile( "output" );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        if( args.length == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Usage: WordCount <file>" );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }

        wordCountJava8( args[ 0 ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the Arrays.asList from the code

    JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap( s ->  s.split( " " ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flatMap function should return Collection's Iterator object.

```
FlatMapFunction<T, R>:
        Iterable<R> call(T t)
```

**Replace-**

```
JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap( s -> Arrays.asList( s.split( " " ) ) );
```

**With:**

```
JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Iterable

```
 JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(
          new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() { public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
              return Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));
            }});
```

Or

```
JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator());
```

Comment: First approach will not compile, expected return type is Iterator.